# How to change heights of buttons in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

There's an Edittext, a default button with no background image and a button with scan image of 148x48 dimension, on its right. I want heights of both the buttons and edittext equal, but I am not able to change their heights. Please help..

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_edttext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Scan or Manual enter a barcode"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="View Stock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_new"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: All those widgets are layout horizontally?

Comment: Yes all widgets are placed horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Give your linear layout a height say 50dp & assign match_parent in height parameter of each widget.(Edittext,button)

Comment: It didn't help, Instead it made the height of 1st button lesser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_edttext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Scan or Manual enter a barcode"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick"
            android:text="View Stock" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_new"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your EditText Height make it matchparent

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Scan or Manual enter a barcode"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

you will get the EditText height equal to your buttons.

Comment: It made the height of edittext equal to buttons height but buttons height are not equal .

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_edttext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="Scan or Manual enter a barcode"
        android:ellipsize="end"
     />

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:text="View Stock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/camera_new"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```